# Why my array removes all from product id while I say only when product id and sizes/colors exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have an array like this:

```
    "products": Array [
      {
        product_id: '1',
        options: [
          {
            size: 'XS',
            color: 'blue'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        product_id: '1',
        options: [
          {
            size: 'S',
            color: 'red'
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
```

So I want to remove the item where the payload is equal with the product id, size and color.

```
      state.cart = state.cart.filter((el => 
        el.products?.id !== action.payload.id && 
        el.products?.options[0].color !== action.payload.options[0].color && 
        el.products?.options[0].size !== action.payload.options[0].size
        ));
```

The payload is right, but he removes both objects. So what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: hmm.. maybe because the array has "product_id", but you are comparing el.products?.id !== action.payload.id..

Answer (score 2):

Chaining `&&`s means that all 3 conditions will have to be fulfilled for the return value to be truthy - the id must not match, the color must not match, and the size must not match. But your ID does match. Use `||` instead, so that a single non-matching value will return true (and include the result in the final array).

You should also use `product_id`, not `id` (since that's the name of the key in your data structure).

You should also not assign directly to state. Assuming that this is inside a reducer and you want to update only the `.cart` property, you'll want

```
return {
  ...state,
  cart: state.cart.filter(el =>
    el.products?.product_id !== action.payload.product_id ||
    el.products?.options[0].color !== action.payload.options[0].color ||
    el.products?.options[0].size !== action.payload.options[0].size
  )
};
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance its for my understanding, can you please tell me why you used || instead of && when he wants to filter replicas but above code will filter items if any of the condition is true? if some other product comes in with same color or size it will be filtered regardless

Comment: i think the && operator was for when all datas are matches. So i think then it would remove

Comment: @WajeehHasan Speak it out loud if you want. With the original code: "Include this item in the result if the ID doesn't match and the color doesn't match and the size doesn't match." Using `||` instead: "Include this item in the result if the ID doesn't match or the color doesn't match or the size doesn't match." See the difference? This way, all non-replicas will be included in the result.

Comment: thank you very much for the clean explaining!!